# What is the replacement for FuzzyMinimumSimilarity in Nest 2, Elasticsearch 2.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-2.0, nest2

I'm upgrading to Nest 2 (elasticsearch 1.x to 2.3), but notice on breaking changes that FuzzyMinimumSimilarity and OnFieldsWithBoost are gone. How should i replace this code below to Nest v2?

```
new SearchDescriptor<T>().Type(searchTypes).Query(q =>q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(fuzzy).FuzzyMinimumSimilarity(0.7)));
```

And for `FuzzyMaxExpansions(0.7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the [fuzziness options available on `query_string` query in NEST 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/query-string-usage.html) (use latest 2.5.8)

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs =>qs
            .Fields(f => f
                .Field(ff => ff.Name, 3)
                .Field(ff => ff.Content, 0.5)
            )
            .Query("fuzzy")
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(3))
            .FuzzyMaxExpansions(2)
            .FuzzyPrefixLength(4)
            .FuzzyRewrite(MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTerms(3))
        )
    )
);
```

which yields

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "fuzzy",
      "fuzzy_max_expansions": 2,
      "fuzziness": 3,
      "fuzzy_prefix_length": 4,
      "fields": [
        "name^3",
        "content^0.5"
      ],
      "fuzzy_rewrite": "top_terms_3"
    }
  }
}
```

Also take a look at the [release blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch) and [breaking changes between 1.x and 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/breaking-changes.html) documentation

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still i don't see the replacement for FuzzyMinimumSimilarity(0,7)...is there something equivalent for this?

Comment: The replace is `Fuzziness`. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_changes_to_queries for `fuzzy_min_sim`